# Strange RAM behaviour when transforming list of texts to numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a python list of very different size of texts. 
When I try to convert that list to a Numpy array, I got very big spikes in Memory.

I am using `np.array(list_of_texts)` for the conversion. 
Please find below the line per line memory usage that is returned by `memory_profiler` of an example of list of texts conversion.

```py
from memory_profiler import profile
import numpy as np
```

```py
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     4     58.9 MiB     58.9 MiB   @profile
     5                             def f():
    23     59.6 MiB      0.3 MiB       small_texts = ['a' for i in range(100000)]
    24     60.4 MiB      0.8 MiB       big_texts = small_texts + [''.join(small_texts)]
    26     61.4 MiB      0.0 MiB       a = np.array(small_texts)
    27  38208.9 MiB  38147.5 MiB       b = np.array(big_texts)
```

I suspect the problem comes from the different size of the texts in the list.

Any idea why this is happening? 
How can I keep a reasonable in-ram memory while converting a list of texts to a numpy array?

Comment: maybe numpy is allocating an array of 10001 elements, each large enough to hold 10000 chars

Comment: I believe numpy arrays can only handle one datatype such as bytes

Comment: @qwr that's what I'm suspecting, it's allocating a size of 100000 chars for each element of the array. It's not the case for the list though

Comment: python lists aren't numpy arrays. python lists can store arbitrary types